# Creating a new object from array of objects and grouping by specific matching key/value

Tags: javascript

Example of the object data I am dealing with

```
var myData = [{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "interest": "Baseball"
},
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 21,
  "interest": "Baseball"
},
{
  "name" : "Sally",
  "age" : 29,
  "interest": "Tennis"
}]
```

I am trying to figure out the easiest way to group them by interests. I am open to using lodash or underscore, but I cannot get the final result to look like this....

I want this to be the output:

```
[{ "Baseball" : [{
                  "name": "John",
                  "age" : 30
                 },
                 {
                  "name" : "Bob",
                  "age" : 21
                 }]
 },
 { "Tennis" : [{
                 "name" : "Sally",
                 "age" : 21
               }]
 }];
```

Basically, each interest becomes a new object key containing all of the matched values within arrays.

I am having trouble constructing this output. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I prefer to use lodash/underscore to keep things very easy.

Thank you!

Comment: You want the result to be an array of objects that each have a different key? That seems inconvenient. Why not have the result be an object? `{Baseball: [...], Tennis: [...]}`

Comment: That could be fine. I just need to have each of the objects grouped to the correct key. That would be fine. I am open to the most streamlined way.

Answer (score 2):

A group-by operation can be done by matching values in a dictionary (hashtable). In JavaScript all objects are dictionaries with property-names as the keys, for values we use arrays.

For example (press the "Run code snippet" button below to see the results):

```js
function groupBy( input, propertyName ) {
    
    var output = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        
        var groupByValue = input[i][propertyName];
        if( !(groupByValue in output) ) {
            output[ groupByValue ] = [];
        }

        var dolly = cloneObjectButIgnoreProperty( input[i], propertyName );
        output[ groupByValue ].push( dolly );
    }

    return output;
}

function cloneObjectButIgnoreProperty( value, ignorePropertyName ) {
    
    var dolly = {};
    var propertyNames = Object.keys( value );
    for( var i = 0; i < propertyNames .length; i++ ) {
        var propertyName = propertyNames[i];
        if( propertyName == ignorePropertyName ) continue;
        dolly[propertyName ] = value[propertyName ];
    }
    return dolly;
}

var myData = [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 30,
        "interest": "Baseball"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 21,
        "interest": "Baseball"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Sally",
        "age" : 29,
        "interest": "Tennis"
    }
];

var groupedByInterest = groupBy( myData, 'interest' );
console.log( "By interest:" );
console.log( groupedByInterest );

var groupedByName = groupBy( myData, 'name' );
console.log( "By name:" );
console.log( groupedByName );

var groupedByAge = groupBy( myData, 'age' );
console.log( "By age:" );
console.log( groupedByAge  );
```

Comment: @AndrewLi The OP said in a comment-reply: " I just need to have each of the objects grouped to the correct key. That would be fine. I am open to the most streamlined way." - so I believe my answer is correct, especially as my code preserves the original input objects (instead of cloning them or removing properties) so it will have less memory usage.

Comment: I tested this snippet, it kinda works, but not exactly.

Comment: @Kinduser—"*…and uses old patterns*". Heaven forbid that code should be clear, easy to maintain and compatible with host versions beyond nightlies.

Comment: His solution is fine and better readable for people who are new to JS, but he missed a `transform` function to transform the objects to get rid of the unwanted "interest" key.

Comment: @cyrix I've added a function that clones the object and removes the specified property.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Array.reduce`  for this:

```js
var myData = [
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "interest": "Baseball"
},
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 21,
  "interest": "Baseball"
},
{
  "name" : "Sally",
  "age" : 29,
  "interest": "Tennis"
}];

var result = myData.reduce(function(entities, obj) {
   entities[obj.interest] = (entities[obj.interest] || []).concat({
      name: obj.name,
      age: obj.age
   });
   return entities;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

A little bit more general approach:

```js
function groupBy(data, key, tFunc) {
   mapFunc = (typeof tFunc === "function")? tFunc: function(o) { return o };
   return (Array.isArray(data)?data:[]).reduce(function(entities, o) {
     if(o[key]) {
       entities[o[key]] = (entities[o[key]] || []).concat(tFunc(o));
     }
     return entities;
   }, {});
}


// test code
var myData = [
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "interest": "Baseball"
},
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 21,
  "interest": "Baseball"
},
{
  "name" : "Sally",
  "age" : 29,
  "interest": "Tennis"
}];

var result = groupBy(myData, "interest", function(o) { return { name: o.name, age: o.age}});
console.log(result);
var result2 = groupBy(myData, "age", function(o) { return o.name});
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `Array.prototype.reduce()` function:

```js
var myData = [{ "name": "John", "age": 30, "interest": "Baseball" }, { "name": "Bob", "age": 21,     "interest": "Baseball" }, { "name" : "Sally", "age" : 29, "interest": "Tennis" }],

    result = myData.reduce(function (r, o) {
        r[o.interest] = r[o.interest] || [];
        r[o.interest].push({name: o.name, age: o.age});
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myData = [{name:"John",age:30,interest:"Baseball"},{name:"Bob",age:21,interest:"Baseball"},{name:"Sally",age:29,interest:"Tennis"}],
    result = [],
    interests = [...new Set(myData.map(v => v.interest))];
    
    interests.forEach(v => result.push({ [v] : [] }));
    myData.forEach((v,i) => result.forEach((c,i) => Object.keys(c)[0] == v.interest ? result[i][v.interest].push({name: v.name, age: v.age}) : c))
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted `name` and `age` keys

Comment: @AndrewLi It's fine now, I think.